# Blazor: BitDatePicker show validation message. How to modify the message?

Tags: validation, blazor, blazor-server-side

```
<BitDatePicker @bind-Value="Model.Date"
                                           AllowTextInput="true"
                                           DateFormat="yyyy/M/d"
                                           GoToToday="امروز" Placeholder="تاریخ را وارد کنید"
                                          Culture="PersianCultureHelper.GetFaIrCultureByFarsiNames()"
                                           Style="width:150px; display:inline-block;">
</BitDatePicker>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B45TB.png)

how to change(modify) the default validation message of this component?

I create a class that inherits from "ValidationAttribute" to override the error message by custom regex validation. but two messages show when the input is not valid.

I don't want to use "Require" attribute. it should show the message when the input is not valid.

Comment: Hi, what is `BitDatePicker`?  I'm assuming a component from a library somewhere, but which one?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis  Hi! From this website:
https://components.bitplatform.dev/components/date-picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that simple.  It's hard coded into the component.

However there is a way.

`BitDatePicker` is a component that emulates a standard `InputBase` type component, though it doesn't implement `InputBase`.  The validation message is generated in `TryParseValueFromString' which looks like this:

```cs
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out DateTimeOffset? result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        if (value.HasNoValue())
        {
            result = null;
            validationErrorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, DateFormat ?? Culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, Culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime parsedValue))
        {
            result = new DateTimeOffset(parsedValue, DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset);
            validationErrorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }

        result = default;
        validationErrorMessage = $"The {DisplayName ?? FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field is not valid.";
        return false;
    }
```

So we can create a child component and override `TryParseValueFromString`.  Note that you have to "capture" the content generated in the parent and re-gurgitate it in the child.

**MyBitDatePicker**

```cs
@using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

@inherits BitDatePicker

@this.ParentContent

@code {
    public RenderFragment ParentContent;

    public MyBitDatePicker()
    {
        ParentContent = (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out DateTimeOffset? result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        var isValid = base.TryParseValueFromString(value, out result, out validationErrorMessage);

        //Custom message defined here
        validationErrorMessage = $"The {DisplayName ?? FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field ain't right!";
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could prevent the problem in the first place by disabling `AllowTextInput`.  The user then can't select an invalid date.

Comment: thanks! it's worked.  how could i replace [Display(Name ="DATE")] instead of parameters in validationErrorMessage ?
it's a date annotetion in my DTO.

Comment: I Edit my last comment:
 it's a data annotation in my DTO

Comment: There are two types of message.  Any messages generated by the Input control are generic type validation messages.  Any messages that are implementation specific should use some form of data class based validation and get generated by the appropriate validator.  If you're using data annotations then that's the `<DataAnnotationsValidator />`.  Don't try and mix up the two.